# Solidity compile error. (Contract should be marked as abstract.)

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

**I have two questions.**

**1) I am getting the following error:**

```
TypeError: Contract "MyToken" should be marked as abstract.
 --> contracts/MyToken.sol:8:1:
```

According to my understanding, contract should be abstract when there is a unimplemented function. Here I have the function foo. But still getting this error?

**2) Also I want write a constructor which passes totalSupply_ to the contract. Is it possible to implement in the way I have done?**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

//import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';

contract MyToken is ERC20 {

    uint256 private _totalSupply;
    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    constructor(string memory name_,string memory symbol_, uint totalSupply_ ) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
        _totalSupply = totalSupply_;
    }

    function foo() external  returns (uint) {
        uint temp;
        temp = 1+1;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

//import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';

contract MyToken is ERC20 {

    uint256 private _totalSupply;
    constructor(string memory name_,string memory symbol_, uint totalSupply_ )  ERC20(name_, symbol_) {
        _totalSupply = totalSupply_;
    }

    function foo() external  returns (uint) {
      uint temp;
      temp = 1+1;
      return temp;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inheriting from `ERC20` but you are not calling its constructor

```
constructor(string memory name_,string memory symbol_,uint totalSupply_)ERC20("name","SYM") {
     _name = name_;
    _symbol = symbol_;
    _totalSupply = totalSupply_;
}
```

In your case you have to call `ERC20("name","SYM")` because `ERC20` is inheriting from an `abstract Context` class.

```
contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata {
```

if you did not inherit from `Context` you would not have to call `ERC20("name","SYM")`

```
contract ERC20 is IERC20, IERC20Metadata {
```

Since you are calling `ERC20("name","SYM")` you are actually setting name and symbol so you dont have to set them in `MyToken` constructor:

```
uint256 private _totalSupply;
constructor(uint totalSupply_ )ERC20("name","SYM") {
    _totalSupply = totalSupply_;
}
```